# How do you store an empty integer vs storing zero

Tags: c++, sqlite

Im sure I am missing something here, but here goes anyway.

I am having an issue with my SQLite database, when accessing an integer field which has not been set, I am getting 0 in return. This is documented behaviour, although is not helping me as I dont know whether the the cell is empty of if indeed is is supposed to be zero.

My one idea was to write NULL into the field if it is empty. Will that work? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: That's what NULL is for!

Comment: I don't use SQLite, but I know other DBs have something like DBNull to check for NULL value vs. actual value (assumes nullable column)

Comment: not quite  @crashmstr thanks though!

Comment: @Stoff81 how is this different? You first check the data to see if it's null or not. Then you'll know if the `0` is really a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

using NULL values to signal that the value hasn't been set is fairly standard. you might want to use a DEFAULT value for the column - and have that default be NULL.